# Angular Material v6 Mat-Footer - "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to implement a footer row into a mat-table component after recently upgrading to angular 6 for this purpose, but after adding both the mat-footer-cell and mat-footer-row elements in the table, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
>   at MatFooterRowDef.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkFooterRowDef.extractCellTemplate (vendor.js:17400)

The table still appears on the page, but with no data, no footer row, and a T symbol where to the right of each column heading.

HTML:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="total">

    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 15%; flex: none">Total</mat-header-cell>

    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" style="width: 15%; flex: none">{{item.total | currency: 'GBP'}}</mat-cell>

    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>

  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></mat-header-row>

  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns" (click)="editItem(row)"></mat-row>

  <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>

</mat-table>
```

Comment: does the table display normally without the `mat-footer-row`?

Comment: Yes, no problems until I added the footer elements

Comment: Are you perhaps able to recreate this error in a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/angular/klengxeqvdd

Comment: Amazing @MichaelDoye Your Example was the solution for me.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

FIXED: This was not made clear in the material documentation, but **all** columns must contain a `<mat-footer-cell/>` element, even if only one column will contain content.

Comment: Absolutely true. If you want to show footer content then each column must contain **footer** cell. I accomplished this in another way: `<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>`.

Comment: alternatively, you can also restrict the columns to be displayed in footer. `<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['total']"></tr>`. This would be useful in scenarios when you have to use `colspan`.

Comment: True. Even columns defined for check boxes require this.

Comment: even in the material documentation they somehow have an example where this is not true. Super misleading. google gunna google

Answer (score 9):

You can define your own "tableFooterColumns" variable.

```
tableFooterColumns: string[] = ['total'];
```

and use it in the template (change "colspan" for your needs):

```
 <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="tableFooterColumns" colspan="2"></tr>
```

Answer (score 8):

Need to include **mat-footer-cell** for each column:

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="categoryName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </mat-cell>
      
      //This is the part for which the code is breaking
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Your footer column Name will goes here </mat-footer-cell>**
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="categoryName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </mat-cell>
      
      //This need to be included in all your columns
      <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Your 2nd footer column Name will goes here </mat-footer-cell>**
    </ng-container>
    <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-footer-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For new comes, you need a foot in each column from your table:

```
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 demo-table">

            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
                <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- age Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
                <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{your information}} </td>

            </ng-container>

...
            <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>

        </table>
```