# Mat Table Footer Angular v15

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, documentation

I am trying to use the mat table in my angular 15 `<tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>` in the correct location at the bottom, and displayedColumns is working for other table portions I get this error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'template')
    at MatFooterRowDef.extractCellTemplate (table.mjs:415:38)
    at table.mjs:1904:27
```

What other things do I need to add/remove/import when using this? I have imported MatTableModule

Tired of the Angular Mat documentation just being legitimately wrong and unexplanatory.

Files: TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'saa-prior-sales',
  templateUrl: './prior-sales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prior-sales.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CurrencyPipe, MatTableModule],
})
export class PriorSalesComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() sales?: IVehicleDetails[]; //New Interface for Sale
  //Sort these in descending Date (table cannot be sorted)
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IVehicleDetails[]>();

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'model',
    'style',
    'eng',
    'trans',
    'miles',
    'price',
    'date',
  ];
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const vehicleList = changes['sales'].currentValue;
    this.dataSource = vehicleList;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div
  *ngIf="dataSource"
  class="w-full p-6 mt-0 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow md:mb-4 sm:mb-4 ng-star-inserted saa-green">
  <div class="p-2 mb-4 text-xl font-medium saa-blue">Prior Sales</div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Location -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="model">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Model</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.vehicle?.location }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- LaneLot Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="style">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Style</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">{{ sale.lane }}/{{ sale.lot }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- VIN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="eng">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Eng</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.eng }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- VIN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="trans">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Trans</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.eng }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- VIN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="miles">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Miles</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.eng }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- VIN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.eng }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- VIN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
        {{ sale.date | date }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

it works if i take away the mat-footer-row, as soon as i add that its busted

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: Added Full Code Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the cells specified in the `*matFooterRowDef` must have `*matFooterCellDef` present inside `matColumnDef`

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
      {{ sale.date | date }}
    </td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td> <!--  must be present if you have the property in matFooterRowDef array! --> 
  </ng-container>
```

code

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div
  *ngIf="dataSource"
  class="w-full p-6 mt-0 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow md:mb-4 sm:mb-4 ng-star-inserted saa-green">
  <div class="p-2 mb-4 text-xl font-medium saa-blue">Prior Sales</div>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <!-- Location -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="model">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Model</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.vehicle?.location }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- LaneLot Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="style">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Style</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">{{ sale.lane }}/{{ sale.lot }}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- VIN Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="eng">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Eng</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.eng }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- VIN Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="trans">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Trans</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.eng }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- VIN Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="miles">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Miles</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.eng }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- VIN Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.eng }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- VIN Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
          {{ sale.date | date }}
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>100</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatTableModule],
})
export class App {
  sales?: any[] = [
    {
      model: 'test',
      style: 'test',
      eng: 'test',
      trans: 'test',
      miles: 'test',
      price: 'test',
      date: 'test',
    },
  ]; //New Interface for Sale
  //Sort these in descending Date (table cannot be sorted)
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any[]>();

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'model',
    'style',
    'eng',
    'trans',
    'miles',
    'price',
    'date',
  ];
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const vehicleList = changes['sales'].currentValue;
    this.dataSource = vehicleList;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ew4s42?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: thanks! just figured it out. Odd that the documentation explicitly alludes that this doesnt have to be true

Answer (score 0):

Each column that you put in *matFooterRowDef needs a mat-footer-cell td element. This is not what the documentation says at all, and even shown oppositely in the example... Terrible Documentation. Found the answer here on another thread
[Angular Material v6 Mat-Footer - "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641359/angular-material-v6-mat-footer-cannot-read-property-template-of-undefined)